# Gathering column stats throwing error

Tags: hive

When I gather stats on columns of a table its throwing an error.

```
hive> ANALYZE TABLE customer COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS;
FAILED: NullPointerException null
```

And also if I query select * from customer; it's working.

If I use any where condition it's throwing error.

```
select * from customer where cust_id=45633;

FAILED: NullPointerException null
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it print detailed stacktrace on stdout ? If yes please paste it in question.

Comment: No. Its printing only FAILED: NullPointerException null

Comment: In that case , need to check error reported in hiveserver log and table schema(column data type and if it is partitioned etc.). May be you are hitting HIVE-14773.